# Ignoring middle group in regular expression substitute

Tags: python, regex

I need to substitute multiple values and regex seems like the right tool.
The problem I’m facing is that I need to leave the middle part of the match string.

```
BasicUtil::EpgToInnerEpgString(sTmpAbc)
BasicUtil::EpgToInnerEpgOID(sTmpXyz)
BasicUtil::EpgToInnerEpgBool(sTmpAbc)
BasicUtil::EpgToInnerEpgInt(sTmpAsd)
BasicUtil::EpgToInnerEpgLong(sTmpAxx)
BasicUtil::EpgToInnerEpgShort(sTmpAny)
```

I manged to match the entire string, and I was wondering if there is a way to ignore the middle match

```
R2 = re.compile("(BasicUtil::(\w+)\()(\w+)(\))", re.MULTILINE)
R2.subn('', slongString)
```

and this the expected result

`sTmpAbc sTmpXyz  sTmpAbc  sTmpAsd sTmpAxx sTmpAny`

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks to PJProudhon here is the actual code:

```
 R1 = re.compile("(BasicUtil::(\w+)\()(\w+)(\))", re.MULTILINE)
    print(R1.sub('\\3', s))
```

OR

```
R2 = re.compile("BasicUtil::\w+\((\w+)\)", re.MULTILINE)
print(R2.sub('\\1', s))
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "middle" of the string? It looks like you're only trying to get the last part in parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a match for each occurence and store the parameter in group 1, as follows:

```
BasicUtil::\w+\((\w+)\)
```

Replace match by the captured group: `$1`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA1a6A/1).